# jquery mobile custom select pierde el foco al seleccionar una opción

Tags: jquery-mobile

Cuando hago clic en una lista larga , se muestra una nueva ventana con posibles opciones (**en modo custom select**), en este punto tengo dos acciones posibles: cerrar la ventana en cuyo caso funciona bien retorna a la ventana anterior sin perder el foco, pero cuando selecciono una opción este retorna a la ventana anterior perdiendo el foco.

En versiones anteriores 1.0.1 funciona bien.

pero en 1.4.5 no lo hace.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<div class="ui-field-contain">
    <label for="select-custom-20">Long list:</label>
    <select name="select-custom-20" id="select-custom-20" data-native-menu="false">
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
        <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
        <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
        <option value="CA">California</option>
        <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
        <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
        <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
        <option value="FL">Florida</option>
        <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
        <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
        <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
        <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
        <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
        <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
        <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
        <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
        <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
        <option value="ME">Maine</option>
        <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
        <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
        <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
        <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
        <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
        <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
        <option value="MT">Montana</option>
        <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
        <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
        <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
        <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
        <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
        <option value="NY">New York</option>
        <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
        <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
        <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
        <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
        <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
        <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
        <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
        <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
        <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
        <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
        <option value="TX">Texas</option>
        <option value="UT">Utah</option>
        <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
        <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
        <option value="WA">Washington</option>
        <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
        <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

En el sitio web oficial de jquery mobile están los ejemplos:

1.4.5 no funciona https://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/selectmenu-custom/

1.0.1 Trabaja bien !! https://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.0.1/docs/forms/selects/custom.html

¿Alguna sugerencia sobre cómo corregir esto en la versión 1.4.5?